# Entity Framework generate not expected query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have Entity Framework object model with inheritance.

My linq query:

```
Books.ItemsNoTracking.Where(o => o.Id == new Guid("2D46B66E-64CB-4C99-AF94-5C7414048ECF")).First();
```

Expected query:

```
SELECT * FROM  [dbo].[Books] AS [Extent1] 
WHERE cast('2d46b66e-64cb-4c99-af94-5c7414048ecf' as uniqueidentifier) = [Extent1].[Id]
```

But EF generate:

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[Created] AS [Created], 
    [Limit1].[OwnerId] AS [OwnerId], 
    [Limit1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
    [Limit1].[PhysicalUnitId] AS [PhysicalObjectId]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[PhysicalObjectId] AS [PhysicalObjectId], 
        [Extent2].[Created] AS [Created], 
        [Extent2].[OwnerId] AS [OwnerId], 
        [Extent2].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
        '0X0X' AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Books] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Objects] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
        WHERE cast('2d46b66e-64cb-4c99-af94-5c7414048ecf' as uniqueidentifier) = [Extent1].[Id]
    )  AS [Limit1]
```

It's most simple example. Other queries are too big and hard to read.

Is there any way to ignore inharitance and create simple query to only one table.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the query that you expect, you should not use the `First()` extension method. That is what adds the `Top 1` clause to the inner query in your example.

I'm not sure which version of Entity Framework you're running but I when I ran similar code on a database I have using EF 6 that comes with Visual Studio, it generated a simple one layer

```
SELECT TOP 1 <columns> FROM <table> WHERE ID = <passed in parameter>
```

Since you're searching against an ID field, it should be safe to assume that you expect a single result, in which case you can use either one of `Single()`, `First()` or `.Take(1)` to ensure you have just one record.

You can read more about these [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/standard-query-operators-in-linq-to-entities-queries#paging-methods) if you wish.